# React Native build failed ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog/glog/logging.h:509:1: note: namespace 'google' begins here namespace google

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, expo-notifications

I want to make my app ready for Push Notification. There fore i use Expo Notifications with React-Native-Firebase (it is a bare workflow app).
Mi error comes from the Podfile.
For firebase i need to add `use_frameworks!`

But than i get this error:

```
node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridge.m:17:9: fatal error: 'RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found
#import "RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

On Github i found that to fix this error i need to remove `use_frameworks!`. But if i remove this, i get the following error:

```
ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog/glog/logging.h:509:1: note: namespace 'google' begins here
namespace google {
^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a solution to fix this?
This are my versions:

> - "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.13.0",
> - "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
> - "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
> - "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
> - "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
> - "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
> - "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.0",
> - "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.0.4",
> - "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.3.0",
> - "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
> - "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2",
> - "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
> - "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
> - "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
> - "expo": "~45.0.0",
> - "expo-image-picker": "^13.1.1",
> - "expo-localization": "^13.0.0",
> - "expo-location": "^14.2.2",
> - "expo-notifications": "^0.15.2",
> - "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
> - "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
> - "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
> - "react": "17.0.2",
> - "react-dom": "17.0.2",
> - "react-native": "0.68.2",
> - "react-native-admob": "v2.0.0-beta.6",
> - "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.1",
> - "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
> - "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
> - "react-native-iap": "^8.0.9",
> - "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.23",
> - "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2",
> - "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
> - "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
> - "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
> - "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
> - "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
> - "react-native-web": "0.17.7"

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: did you fix it?